# How to check if template is compatible with older versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, ietester

well we have IETester tool to check a template with different versions of IE but what about other browsers .

I have Last versions of firefox , chrome and opera and I try my template with them .

questions :

1 - do other browsers have the same problem as IE in their different versions ( IE6 has one standard , IE 7 another , IE 8 its own , IE 9 is something else ! ) , so necessary to check template in older versions as we do with IE ?

2- if yes , how to do that ? any tools ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, other browsers have differences in rendering webpages based  on browser version, though they are often not as significant rendering differences in comparison to those in different versions of Internet Explorer.

Some of these rendering differences are documentated at [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/).

Whether it is necessary to check for rendering issues on your template is ultimately your decision which you make based on what level of cross browser compatibility you want to support.

Tools for testing cross browser compatiablity include:

- Having at least one virtual machine and installing all the versions of the browsers you want to test on. If you want to automate web testing you can use a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). This method is one of the most tedious but does allow full control of the rendering settings in each browser and allows debugging with browser tools like Firebug and the relevant Web Developer tools / extensions that come with each browser. (Do it yourself option, Free , only cost being time to setup it up how you want it)
- [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) (Free, just automated screenshots)
- [Adobe Browser Labs](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#) (Free, just automated screenshots)
- [Cross Browser Testing](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/) (Free trial with both interactive testing and Automated Screenshots)
- [Multibrowser Viewer](http://www.multibrowserviewer.com/)  (Free trial with both interactive testing and Automated Screenshots)
- [Browser Stack](http://www.browserstack.com/) (Free trial with both interactive testing and Automated Screenshots)
- [Testing Bot](http://testingbot.com/) (Free trial with both automated interactive testing and Automated Screenshots)
- [Multibrowser](http://www.multi-browser.com/en) (Free trial with interactive testing)
- [Browser Seal](http://www.browserseal.com/) (Free trial, with automated screenshots)
- [Sauce Labs ondemand and Scout](http://saucelabs.com/)(Free trial, with both automated interactive testing and Automated Screenshots )
- [SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx) (Free trial)
- [spoon](http://spoon.net/browsers/) (Free trial, Free trial with interactive testing)
- [Mogotest](http://mogotest.com/)  (Free trial with both automated interactive testing and Automated Screenshots)
- [browserling](http://browserling.com/) ((Free trial, Free trial with interactive testing)
- [browsera](https://www.browsera.com/plans) (Free trial, Free trial with interactive testing)
- [Lunascape](http://www.lunascape.tv/) (Free, with side by side interactive testing, though only 3 different browsers)

Answer (score 0):

As a local tool I would add [BrowseEmAll](http://www.browseemall.com) to the list (Windows only).